# How do I translate a call of the LINQ extension method Select into a corresponding expression tree

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework-4, expression-trees

The following LINQ query resp. call of the extension method Select in Visual Basic 2010 is working fine:

```vb
Dim qAvSalary = qJobData.Select(Function(e) e.AvSalary)
```

But doing so I am not able to specify the name of property I want the query (e.g. AvSalary) using a string variable. This should be possible if I use a LINQ expression tree. Searching and trying a long time on how to translate the query to a corresponding expression tree was not successful. My final approach is:

```vb
' The IQueryable data to query.
Dim queryableData As IQueryable(Of JobData) = qJobData.AsQueryable()
Dim pe As ParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(GetType(JobData), "e")
Dim sPropertyName = "AvSalary"      ' or some other property depending on the business logic
Dim propex = Expression.Property(pe, sPropertyName)

Dim selectCallExpr As MethodCallExpression = Expression.Call(
        GetType(Queryable),
        "Select",
        New Type() {queryableData.ElementType},
        queryableData.Expression,
        Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of JobData, System.Nullable(Of Int32)))(
                    propex,
                    New ParameterExpression() {pe}))
```

Executing this statement throws the following exception:

> Message = "Keine generische Methode "Select" für Typ "System.Linq.Queryable" ist mit den bereitgestellten Typargumenten und Argumenten kompatibel. Es sollten keine Typargumente bereitgestellt werden, wenn die Methode nicht generisch ist. "

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Select has two type paramters. The *from* and the *to* type. Specify both.

Comment: Assuming the property _AvSalary_ is of type _Integer_, what do I have to specify where?

Comment: New Type() {queryableData.ElementType, typeof(int) }

Comment: I tried: 
    New Type() {queryableData.ElementType, GetType(Integer)},

Still the same exception...

Comment: I just solved it. The right Expression is:

        Dim selectCallExpr As MethodCallExpression = Expression.Call(
                GetType(Queryable),
                "Select",
                 New Type() {queryableData.ElementType, **propex.Type**},
                queryableData.Expression,
                Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of JobData, System.Nullable(Of Int32)))(
                            propex,
                            New ParameterExpression() {pe}))